# How to exclude async methods from Code Coverage using ExcludeCodeCoverage attribute in XunitTest Asp.net Core 3.1?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, code-coverage, asp.net-core-3.1, xunit.net

I created an Asp.net Core web application and have Unit testing of XUnit.Net test framework.

The ExcludeCodeCoverage attribute on async methods does not exclude that method from code coverage.

Any solution that I can exclude my async methods from code coverage in Xunit.Net Test Asp.Net Core framework?

Consider the following code example where the method does not get excluded from code coverage even after adding the attribute.

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]        
    public async Task<string> GetName(string userId){}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question actually does not properly describe what problem you are facing, it would be better to share the relevant code for your problem. I suggest you go through [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Tushar- I modified my question